# Write shell script to move oldest file in the directory to the new directory.?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I am new to shell scripting. I am seeking solution for it. If i have 10 files in my directory, Incase the 11th file is added to this directory. I just want to move the oldest file to other directory. I gave naming **Work** for my directory and **regular_archieve** for another directory. I have tried this,

```
work = /home/balaji/work
regular_archieve = /home/balaji/regular_archieve
cd $work
for i in 'ls -t | sed -e '1,10d' | xargs -d '\n' rm -f'
do
 mv $i $regular_archieve
done
```

```
if [ls /backup | wc -1 > 10 | mv /home/balaji/regular-archieve]
 then
   echo "more than 10 n files"
fi
```

```
ls -t | sed -e '1,10d' | xargs -d '\n' mv -f regular-archieve
```

But I am not able to move to file to another directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below command to move the oldest file into some other directory :

```
mv $(ls -t /home/balaji/work| tail -1) /home/balaji/regular_archieve/
```

`ls -t`: This command will list all file in the directory sorted by modification time, newest first.

`tail -1`: It will pick the last file which will be the oldest one.

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: You are considering only 11 files in total. What if there are more files than that.?

Comment: @oguzismail I'll definitely read it. I can try to do it with find as well.

Comment: @LokeshM I'm not considering any number of files. `ls` will look for all the files in directory and tail will pick the oldest one.

Comment: @Pacifist this is one where control characters in filenames as well as the default for `--group-directories-first` setting can bite you. The links for why not to parse `ls` are well worth drawing from, but for simple filenames this is the quick way I would do it.

Comment: Thanks @Pacifist for your answer. But I received this error,
`./regular-archieve.sh: line 1: tail -1: command not found`
`mv : missing distination file operand after '/home/balaji/regular_archieve/'`

Comment: @NagabalajiVijayakumar Can you try `tail -n 1`

Comment: @Pacifist, I changed as you said, Now, It shows `./regular-archieve.sh: line 1: tail -n: command not found`

Comment: @NagabalajiVijayakumar Does `tail` work on your *nix system? Can you try using it on any file? tail command should not create any issue as far as I know.

Comment: @Pacifist Yes it works on my system. I was trying it all the way but the issue was not ended up.

Comment: @NagabalajiVijayakumar Maybe the last try. Run `which tail` and then run the script. Like in my system this command gives output as `/usr/bin/tail`. So use `/usr/bin/tail -1` inside your script.

Comment: @Pacifist Thanks, It works. Actually the folder has limits only 10 files. By using this script we can mv the oldest file. But here its moving only one oldest file. My problem is, If I add after any number of files than 10th file. it should have to mv all the oldest files and keep only 10 files in the directory.